# How do I separate the boot partition on a filesystem after installation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub-efi

I have a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04. Earlier, I gave ubuntu 80 gb and 12 gb swap (for hibernation) while installing. Now I managed to free another 200 gb from my 1TB HDD and I wanna extend my ubuntu data (/) partition from a /boot partition. How can I do it without reinstalling Ubuntu? How much space should I allocate for /boot?
[This is the output of `fdisk -l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fqJs.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhYX.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2QOh.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1np2l.png) and the output of lsblk [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yUk.png).

Comment: What you can do very much depends on the current partitioning of your filesystem. It may be wise to include the output of `sudo fdisk -l` in your question, and `lsblk`, which will help to identify the current partitions.

Comment: Most desktops do not need /boot as a partition. If you want to separate operating system from data, then a separate partition for /home works. Or you can just create a new ext4 partition, give yourself ownership & permissions, and mount partition to use as some or all of data. Many with large music or video libraries like a separate partition for those and may then backup those up separately. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Basically I want to use a larger partition for the root of the filesystem because on I am running out of space so if I can `extend` or mount / to some bigger partition that'd be great